# Question about Gauss's Lemma?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

This is an excerpt from my book:

> Suppose that $P(x)$ has integer coefficients and has the zero $x=2/3$ ... By the factor theorem, $P(x)=(x-\dfrac 23)Q(x)$. But what kind of coefficients does $Q(x)$ have? All that we know for sure is that the coefficients must be rational ... We can write $P(x)=(3x-2)S(x)$, where $S(x)= \dfrac {Q(x)}{3}$. We know that $P(x)$ has integer coefficients; can we say the same thing about $S(x)$? Indeed we can; this is **Gauss's Lemma**:
>
> $$\text{If a polynomial with integer coefficients can be factored into}$$
>
> $$\text{polynomials with rational coefficients, it can also be factored}$$
>
> $$ \text{into primitive polynomials with integer coefficients}$$

My problem is that I don't see how Gauss's Lemma implies that $S(x)$ must have integer coefficients. All that the lemma is saying is that there exist two primitive polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $P(x)=f(x)g(x)$. I don't know how to deduce that $(3x-2)$ and $S(x)$ are such polynomials.

Comment: But *primitive* means, in particular, polynomials with integer coefficients. You know that $2/3$ is a root and so there's a linear factor with integer coefficients having $2/3$ as a root. The only primitive such linear polynomial is $3x-2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Let's say $P(x)$ is a $10^{th}$ degree polynomial with integer coefficients, and it can be factored into two primitive $5^{th}$ degree polynomials, and one of the roots of one of the polynomials is $\dfrac 23$. This already satisfies Gauss's Lemma, and it doesn't seem give us information about what happens if we were to factor $P$ as a $1^{st}$ degree times a $9^{th}$ degree polynomial instead.

Comment: It applies to any particular factorization you have!  Your statement of the Gauss Lemma does not make that clear. It seems vague, I can see. If you have $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, with $f$ a primitive integer polynomial and $g,h$ rational polynomials, then $f(x)=\tilde g(x)\tilde h(x)$, with $\tilde g,\tilde h$ primitive integer polynomials *and* $\tilde g(x) = c_1g(x)$ and $\tilde h(x) = c_2 h(x)$ for some rational numbers $c_1,c_2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah okay thanks that is much more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gauss lemma can be stated in form that product of primitive polynomials is primitive polynomial. It is not loss of generality to assume that $P$ is primitive. Now, we know that $S(x)$ has rational coefficients, so there exists primitive polynomial with integer coefficients $S_0(x)$ such that $S_0(x) = qS(x)$. Thus, $qP(x) = (3x-2)S_0(x)$, so $qP(x)$ must be primitive which implies that $q = \pm 1$, i.e. $S$ has integer coefficients.

---

Let me do the general statement. Let $p(x)$ be primitive polynomial with integer coefficients and let $p(x) = f(x)g(x)$ be its factorization over $\mathbb Q$. Then, there exist primitive polynomials with integer coefficients $f_0$ and $g_0$ and rational numbers $q_1$ and $q_2$ such that $q_1f(x) = f_0(x)$, $q_2g(x) = g_0(x)$. Let $q = q_1q_2$. Then we have $qp(x) = f_0(x)g_0(x)$ and by $f_0$ and $g_0$ being primitive, $qp$ is primitive as well. This implies $q=\pm 1$.

Indeed, let $q = a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ relatively prime and let $\alpha_i$ be coefficients of $p$. First of all, we have that $a\alpha_i/b$ are all integers, so $b$ divides all $\alpha_i$. By assumption of $p$ being primitive, $b = 1$. Finally, we have that $ap$ is primitive, and since $p$ has integer coefficients, $a = \pm 1$. Finally, this gives us factorization $p(x) = \pm f_0(x)g_0(x)$ over $\mathbb Z$.